# Laravel Query Builder with Join and If condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

how can you use the if else condition in the results of the query builder?

```
$data = DB::table('peminjaman')
                        ->select('peminjaman.id as id_peminjaman',
                                'reads.pageread',
                                'books.*',
                                'pengarang.name as pengarang_name'
                                )
                        ->join('reads','reads.id_book','peminjaman.id_book')
                        ->join('books','books.id','=','reads.id_book')
                        ->join('pengarang','pengarang.id','=','books.idpengarang')
                        ->where('peminjaman.id_user',$user->id)
                        ->orderBy($sort,$urut)
                        ->get();
```

i want to use some if conditioning like this, in real case there will be lots of other where, and the table used for where I have declared a join as above

```
  if($statment=="notread"){
            where('reads.pageread', '=',0);
        }
        if($statment=="read"){
            where('reads.pageread', '=',1);
        }
        if($statment=="bigbook"){
            where('books.bigbook', '=',1);
        }
```

Comment: So do you mean adding a `->where` based on a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy paste your query and some touch up, here's the result. Just improve your query builder in case you want to make it more complex

```
$data = DB::table('peminjaman')
->select(
         'peminjaman.id as id_peminjaman',
         'reads.pageread',
         'books.*',
         'pengarang.name as pengarang_name'
        )
->join('reads', 'reads.id_book', '=', 'peminjaman.id_book')
->join('books', 'books.id', '=', 'reads.id_book')
->join('pengarang', 'pengarang.id', '=', 'books.idpengarang')
->where('peminjaman.id_user', $user->id)
->when($statement, function($query, $statement){
      if($statement === 'notread'){
            return $query->where('reads.pageread', 0);
      } elseif($statement === 'read'){
            return $query->where('reads.pageread', 1);
      } elseif($statment=="bigbook"){
            return $query->where('books.bigbook', 1);
      }
})
->orderBy($sort, $urut)
->get();
```

Comment: i try hat but, i get error in line ->orderBy

Comment: show me your error, im not a wizard who knows the errors

Comment: it's done now, just need ")" in up ->orderBy so  })

Comment: thanks, i edited my code above in case anyone want to copy my codeblock

Comment: do you know how to parsing variabel $user in when? like return $query->where('books.iduser', $user->id);

Comment: just add use($user) after function()

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel's conditional clause 'when' like this :

this is a sample code as you said there can be many where clauses . You can use it as it fit's you

```html
$test = 2;    
DB::table('users')->when(($test==2),function ($query){
            return $query->where('id',2);
        })->get();
```